Installing Python Packages on Linux
I have some python code that I have written on my windows computer and runs and works fine. I am trying to get that same code to work on my Linux computer in Visual Studio Code. I have installed all the libraries that I intend to import but I am getting an error saying there is no module with that name.
I am using this in my terminal in my virtual environment:
pip install imutils
It is giving me this error:
import imutils ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imutils'
When I try and install imutils it tells me the requirement is already satisfied and gives me a path directory.
I have tried installing imutils, reinstalling, creating another virtual environment.

Can you share the path of where the module is installed? Most probably you might have installed it at different path.

Yeah here it is:
Requirement already satisfied: imutils in ./myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (0.5.4)

Now open a python terminal import the module sys  and print(sys.path) check if the path you provided can be found in the list.

first in your in windows machine execute this command:
"pip freeze > requirements.txt"
above command search you project and finds all packages you use in your project and save it in requirements.txt file.
second in your linux machine create directory for your project and copy all files and requirements.txt file in it.
third with "python3 -m venv venv" create virtual env for your project.
open terminal in your project directory path and use "source ./venv/bin/activate"
it's activates python env your project and in this env enter below command
"pip install -r ./requirements.txt"
with this you create exact packages as your windows machine in your linux machine. i think it's gonna fix your problem.
